# What is going on with my shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason, regardless of how long i hold the shout button and/or what max level it is, i can only use level one shouts.  It even plays the charging up animation for level 2/3 shouts, but once i release the button, only the level one shout activates.  Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on with the game?

Comment: That’s strange. Do you have any older saved games where that doesn’t happen? Has it always been happening?

Comment: It only started happening recently, but i am not sure what caused it.  Has this happened to anyone else? Or is it just me?

Comment: I tried re-loading the save, but its still happening.

Comment: Something tells me that i have to close down Skyrim and re-open it.

Comment: Are you using a console? Also, could you try a different controller? I can’t cast two-handed spells anymore because my mouse is too squirrelly... maybe your button is broken.

Comment: Have you tried multiple shouts? There’s one shout that’s difficult to get it to activate.

Comment: If it's just one shout, which one?

Comment: are you sure you are unlocking the shouts with dragon souls?